# Does PHP PDO have a built in method to return a result as array with ID as key?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, php-5.5

Say I have a table

```
id,f1,f2
10,'aaa','aaaaaa'
20,'bbb','bbbbb'
```

Is there a way using PDO to query the DB and get the results as array:

```
[10=>['aaa','aaaaa'], 20=>['bbb','bbbbb'] ]
```

Comment: There's only `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR`. It's easiest to post-arrange a `fetchAll` list per [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column)+[`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine).

Comment: no. even if pdo did have something like that, how should it handle multi-field PKs for a table? what if the ID fields aren't selected in the query?

Comment: @mario that is good enough for what I need. Put as answer and I will accept (Although, does not answer if I have more than 2 fields).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.
That's one of things that make PDO so great.

All you need is `PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE` constant:

```
$data = $pdo->query('SELECT id,f1,f2 FROM t')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
```

will give you desired result.

You may wish to browse other [fetch modes for PDO](http://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchall) in the article I wrote recently.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of you would have to create it as you loop through your results

```
 $array = [];

 foreach($pdoResults as $result)
 {
     $array[$result['id']] = [$result[$f1],$result[$f2]];
 }
```

Comment: Worth noting that this format will not work in older versions of PHP. It should be $array[$result['id']] = array($result[$f1],$result[$f2]); instead for < 5.6 (I believe).

Answer (score -1):

No, PDO does not have such functionality. You have to process the result set.

Comment: This is an incorrect statement, fetch mode `PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE` does what the OP wants